Using percentage value for absolutely positioned elements doesn't work when parent has padding
Using percentage value for absolutely positioned elements doesn't work when parent has padding.
code:
<View className="w-full py-40 mt-10 bg-gray-300 border border-black">
  <View className="absolute bottom-1/2 size-20 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-red-default">
    <Text>some text</Text>
  </View>
</View>

changing py-40 for h-[200px] then the absolute child positions itself correctly in the middle.
